# Understanding touch events

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch

I'm trying to make some of my libraries work with touch devices, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how they're supported and how they work.

Basically, there are [5 touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events), but it seems there's consensus among mobile browsers only on the `touchstart` event (duh). I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpUsA/4/) as a test case.

I've tested this on my Galaxy Note with Android 4 on board, but you can check the link with a desktop browser too.

The goal is to try to figure out how to handle taps, double taps and long taps. Nothing fancy.

Basically, this is what happens:

The **Android stock browser** doesn't fire touch events. It just tries to emulate mouse clicks with taps, firing `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `click` events consecutively, but double taps just zoom in and out tha page.

**Chrome** for Android fires the touchstart event when the finger touches the screen. If it's released soon enough, it fires then `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `touchend` and finally `click` events.

In case of *long tap*, after about half a second it fires `mousedown` and `mouseup`, and `touchend` when the finger is lifted, with no `click` event at the end.

If you *move your finger*, it fires a `touchmove` event a couple of times, then it fires a `touchcancel` event, and nothing happens afterwards, not even a `touchend` event when lifting the finger.

A *double tap* triggers the zoom in/out features, but event-wise it fires the combo `touchstart`-`touchevent` twice, with no mouse events fired.

**Firefox** for Android correctly fires the `touchstart` event, and in case of short tap fires `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `touchend` and `click` afterwards.

In case of *long tap*, it fires `mousedown`, `mouseup` and finally `touchend` events. It's the same of Chrome for these things.

But if you *move your finger*, if fires `touchmove` continously (as one may expect) but it doesn *not* fire the `touchleave` event when the finger leaves the element with the event listener, and doesn't fire the `touchcancel` event when the finger gets out of the browser viewport.

For *double taps*, it behaves just like Chrome.

**Opera Mobile** does the same thing of Chrome and Firefox for a short tap, but in case of long press activates some sort of sharing feature that I really want to disable. If you move your finger, or double tap, it behaves just like Firefox.

**Chrome beta** does the usual for short taps, but in case of long taps it doesn't fire the `mouseup` event anymore, just `touchstart`, then `mousedown` after half a second, then `touchend` when the finger is lifted. When the finger is moved, now it behaves like Firefox and Opera Mobile.

In case of *double taps*, it doesn't fire touch events *when zooming out*, but only when zooming in.

Chrome beta shows the oddest behaviour, but I can't really complain since it's a beta.

**The question is**: is there a simple and way to try to detect short taps, long taps and double taps in the most common browsers of touch devices?

Too bad I can't test it on iOS devices with Safari, or IE for Windows Phone 7/Phone 8/RT, but if some of you can, your feedback would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Tocca.js? http://gianlucaguarini.github.io/Tocca.js/ It enables all the missing touch events on any kind of device and it's just about 1kb

Answer (score 26):

If you haven't already, I would suggest reading the source code for Hammer.js

https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/blob/master/hammer.js

Between comments and code it's about 1400 lines, there is great documentation and the code is easy to understand.

You can see how the author has chosen to solve a lot of the common touch events:

> hold, tap, doubletap, drag, dragstart, dragend, dragup, dragdown,
>   dragleft, dragright, swipe, swipeup, swipedown, swipeleft, swiperight,
>   transform, transformstart, transformend, rotate, pinch, pinchin,
>   pinchout, touch (gesture detection starts), release (gesture detection
>   ends)

I think after reading the source code you will have much better understanding of how touch events work and how to identify which events the browser is capable of handling.

http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Comment: Interesting piece of code, seems quite complete and extensive. I might take some time analyzing it.

Answer (score 9):

There's a really excellent resource https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/results/ that details the order of events across a staggering number of browsers. It also appears to be updated regularly (in September 2016, it was last updated August 2016).

**The gist is,** essentially everything triggers `mouseover` and related events; most also trigger touch events, which *usually* complete (reach `touchend`) before `mouseover` and then continue to `click` (unless a change to page content cancels this). Those awkward exceptions are thankfully relatively rare (3rd party android browsers and blackberry playbook).

That linked resource goes into an impressive level of detail, here's a sample of the first three of many, many operating system, device and browser tests:

[image]

To summarise some of the key points:

### Mobile browsers

- All listed browsers trigger `mouseover` on the first tap. Only some Windows Phone browsers trigger it on a second tap.
- All trigger `click`. It doesn't specify which cancel `click` if `mouseover` changes the page (I believe most do)
- Most browsers trigger `mouseover` after `touchstart` and `touchend`. This includes iOS7.1 Safari, stock Android, Chrome, Opera and Firefox for Android, and some (not all Windows phone browsers)
- Several Windows Phone browsers (all Windows 8 / 8.1 and one version for 10) and several 3rd-party Android browsers (Dolphin, Maxathon, UC) trigger `mouseover` *after* `touchstart` and `touchend`.
- Only Blackberry Playbook triggers `mouseover` between `touchstart` and `touchend`
- Only Opera Mini and Puffin (3rd party Android browser) lack `touchstart` or `touchend`.

### Desktop browsers

- Reasonably up to date versions of desktop Chrome and Opera behave like their mobile counterparts, `touchstart` and `touchend` followed by `mouseover`.
- Firefox and Microsoft browsers (IE <=11 and many versions of Edge) don't trigger any `touchstart` and `touchend` events.
- No data on Macs, but presumably no Ma browsers support `touchstart` and `touchend` given the scarcity of Mac touchscreen interfaces.

There's also an incredible amount of data on browsers combined with assistive technologies.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can start a timer at`touchstart` and end it on `touchend` and make your choices from there.

Also you can make... let's say swipe, my triggering `touchmove` you can get the coordonates of the "finger" and see how much i traveled before `touchend` gets triggered.

I don't know if there's any simpler way rather than using a touch events library, but i suppose you could write one for simple 'tap', 'double tap', 'swipe' events pretty easily.

Comment: If you think about it, and consider the behaviour of the browsers above, you'll admit that's not easy at all. For example, if you touch an element, then move your finger outside the element and then lift the finger, that wouldn't be a valid "tap", but you can't detect it since `touchleave` is never fired.

Comment: You make a good point, BUT; with proper coding, such us, capturing the element `e.target` (i believe) at touchstart, does it equal with the element on touchend? If no, then it's not a valid tap, it's a trap. I'm not saying coding a library would be easy, but it's not really "hard", i would rank it as "medium" + what's the fun if it's not challenging and making us return on stackoverflow xD

Comment: Coding a library wouldn't be a problem for me, I find it challenging, satisfying and somewhat fun. But your comment just hints at a solution, but how do you build it? Where do you keep the informations about the `touchstart` event? What if a second `touchstart` event is fired meanwhile (multitouch display)? How do you handle long taps? Using `setTimeout`, but what if the finger leaves the element meanwhile? How do you detect it if no touch events are fired? And so on... I'll give a try of course, but I was hoping to find a deep analisys of touch events.

Comment: You cant fire a second touchstart event without the touchend event being fired, hence you cant have two simoultneusly taps, so its no problem. You would keep the information in the variables and reset them at touchend

Comment: That's incorrect, you *can* have a second `touchstart` before the first `touchend` occurs. Moreover, thinking about your answer again leads to the conclusion that it won't help, because the `target` property of the `touchend` event *always* equals the element in which the touch started, *even when the finger was moved outside the element!*

Answer (score 3):

Here is my latest observation on touch and mouse events on Android 4.3

### Opera, Firefox, and Chrome seem to have a standard behavior

1. On Swipe (touchstart-touchmove-touchend):

   1. No mouse event(exluding mouseover) fires.
   2. Mouseover fires only if touchstart and touchend occurs on the same element. (touchstart-touchmove-touchend-mouseover)
   3. If default is prevented on touchstart: the default swipe behavior does not work. no changes occur regarding mouse event firing.
2. On Tap(touchstart-touchend):

   1. All mouse events mouseover-mousemove-mousedown-mouseup-click fire after a delay
   2. If default is prevented on touchstart: only mouseover fires.

**Android default browser has some non-standard behaviors**:

1. Mouseover fires before touchstart which means mouseover always fires.
2. All mouse events fire on Tap, even if the default is prevented on touchstart.