# Anchor tag is not working properly in touch screen devices

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, touch, smooth-scrolling

I've an **anchor** at the bottom of the page, which I am using to scroll to top of the page (to header).

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">Sys.Application.add_load(BindEventToScrolls);</script><%--Since I've achor tag within update panel, to rebind the jquery events after upade panel udates, I am using this line of code--%>
<a class="scrollToTopImg" href="#Header"></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.scrollToTopImg
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 34px;
    z-index: 999;
    right: 5px;
    color:#c1b38e;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-image: url('../Images/scrollToTop.png');
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

I am using following jquery to scroll smoothly

**Jquery:**

```
//BindEventToScrolls() is js function to rebind jquery events after update panel is updated
    function BindEventToScrolls() {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('a').click(function () {
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
                        }, 2000);
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            }
```

Now in my **touch device** when I **touch this anchor tag**, the page **scrolls** to the **top** (to header) smoothly as exactly I wanted, but when I again try to **wipe down to scroll page down**, the page scrolls down but it **again automatically scrolls smoothly towards top**. I've to **wipe down 3-4 times** to finally **scroll down** and make page **stay stable at that position**.

The scrolling functionality **is working exactly fine in desktop and non touch devices**, but it is **not at all working properly in touch devices**.

I think the problem is with the **jquery scroll** which is not able to understand the **touch events**.

Is there any way to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
function BindEventToScrolls() {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('a').click(function () {
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
                        }, 2000);
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            }
```

also try to add some values with offset it locate points for anchor element so add some value with this

Comment: event.preventDefault() removes the hyperlink behavior. Now smooth scrolling is not at all working. Its just behaving like simple hyper-linking with no scrolling animation. For this purpose instead of preventDefault I am using return false, so that I will jumped out of the function and stop triggering the scroll event again. I think the problem is that jquery don't understand touch events.

Comment: palta are you using jquery mobile framework or just web jquery

Comment: no man try for touch event like touch start and touch end it may work try to bind your code with touch events i hope basic trouble u r getting on touch(((http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486804/understanding-touch-events)))refer it

Comment: but there is not touch event I want to trigger, I just triggering scrollTop event which works fine in pc but not in tablet, I don't know why. For touch I am using touchwipe.js for multitouch and wipe events. :(

Comment: jQuery Plugin to obtain touch gestures from iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad, should also work with Android mobile phones (not tested yet!) i hope you r using android palta i seen this comment in its lib

Answer (score 1):

```
var touchstart;
var touchend;
jQuery('.scrollableArea .expanded.dropdown').on('touchstart',function(e) {
    touchstart = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
//console.log(touchstart);
});
jQuery('.scrollableArea .expanded.dropdown').on('touchend', function(e) {
    touchend = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX;
//console.log(touchend );
    if(touchend==touchstart) {
//console.log("Yesss"+jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href'));
     window.location = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
    }
});
```