# Javascript timeout or mouseup event, but not both in Android browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications, event-handling, cross-browser

I'm trying to write a javascript web-app where an action is taken on `mouseup`, and another action is taken after the user has held down the button long enough.  My code works in every browser I have tried on Windows and Linux, but on all three Android browsers I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, and native) I seem to lose the `mouseup` event if the timer fires.

The core of my code seems quite straightforward:

```
btn.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
   myTimer = setTimeout(function(){
     btn.textContent += "t";
     outVal = "b";
   }, 500);
});
btn.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
   clearTimeout(myTimer);
   btn.textContent += outVal;
   outVal = "a"
});
```

Jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wanderinglogic/sycL0e53/

On non-Android browsers, if the user releases the button after a short time it outputs `a`, if the user holds the button it (after 500ms) outputs `t` and then when the user releases the button outputs `b`.

But on Android browsers, if the users releases the button after a short time it still outputs `a`, and if the user holds the button it (after 500ms) still outputs `t`, but then the final button release doesn't output `b`.

Is there some extra event on Android that is interfering with my `mouseup` that I don't know about?

Comment: You, of course have `myTimer` declared in a higher scope than both of these event handling functions, right?

Comment: Probably because they use touchevents and not mouse events.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, I was trying to just put the core of the code in the post.  The complete code is in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Android does (in general) does not have mouse input... On touch would be better way to describe it. And as such the user input works differently then on non-touch interfaces. This whole touchy subject was the death for mouse over events. See: [understanding touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486804/understanding-touch-events)