# how to make a css ::scrollbar behavior like on a touchscreen, all text moveable

Tags: html, css

I've done some touch apps running in kiosk mode on hd-sized screen in fullscreen in chromium. works great, but now I want to serve the site to some peaople checking the content and functionality.

Ok, I can ask them to use the chromium dev mode and switch to the tablet in HD and enjoy the original touch functionality. I tried, but some of them are historian (there are wonderful historians everywhere, but not in this project. (they asked to print the about 2000 content pages)

when using the touch the user can touch on the text area an move the page up and down. when using the mouse there's only the scrollbar. is there a trick to make the textarea moveable with css on non touchscreens.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to make a web element on desktop behave as if it is on mobile and the mouse to be simulated as if it is a touch/tap event you might want to look into Hammer.js: http://hammerjs.github.io/

If you are looking to just disable the mouse hover effect for some elements you can use this CSS:

```
.yourClass {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

There is also a good resource here: [Understanding touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486804/understanding-touch-events)

Comment: I want to scroll the text when I klick into the text area, like it works on touch screens

Comment: There is no default behavior where you click/tap on text on a web page and it automatically scrolls. Try opening any web page on your phone and keep clicking/tapping on any text. You will see nothing will scroll. Therefore what you are asking is not clear at all.

Comment: when I open a site on a touch device I can scroll on the complete site. open this page on a touch device and touch the site.

Comment: If you open any site, including StackOverflow you can touch and scroll the complete site. Therefore what you are describing is either described in a way for a particular mystery person to decipher. Or you are incapable of describing anything.

Comment: hey,slowly, when you open this page in a mobile device you can scroll the page up and down no matter where you touch and move your finger. that's normal. my question is how to get this behavior in a desktop browser. by the way: when starting the chromium dev tools I can simulate these touch option on a desktop device. Ok, perhaps there is a way to do the same with some css tricks.